# How to run uNET (Unity Networking) Host Server for WebGL build - Unity 5.3.5

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking, unity-webgl, unity3d-unet

So I have a game that I want to export to WebGL. It uses Unity's latest networking solution uNET (Unity Networking) and I've selected the *use websockets option.

Currently, WebGL clients cannot be a server. Thus in order to host a game, I am doing it when I run the game through the editor. Then in the browser, I can join the game as a client.

So obviously I don't want to leave my computer on to be the host through the editor while people in the web join as clients.

I'm thinking that I should build the game in standalone and run the standalone game on some server and join the game as host. Then of course I leave the server on 24/7 so anyone can join through the web. But I have no idea how to accomplish this (i.e. what services to use) or if this is even the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a dedicated server or VPS with root access. You can avail this service from many hosting companies like GoDaddy or DreamHost. Get an Ubuntu Linux OS.
2. Create a Standalone headless linux build.
3. Upload it to your server via scp.
4. Run it via ssh.